# Using multiple conditional filter conditions in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am trying to use multiple conditional filters on a data frame , but when the filters ( which would come from drop down select boxes ) are both used then only one of the filters is actually applied, and the second one is ignored. I cant see anything wrong with it , and have tried ifelse which gave the same results

```
# seed values 
item_levels <-c("alpha","beta","omega","omega","beta","alpha","omega")
prod_types <- c("production","development","test","example","test","test","test")
sample <-data.frame(item_levels,prod_types) 

# simulate inputs
selected_item = "omega"
selected_type = "test"


sample   %>%  
  filter(if(selected_item != "all"){
    item_levels == selected_item
  }else{1==1} & 
    if(selected_type != "all"){
      prod_types == selected_type
    }else{1==1}
  ) 
# Further calculations would be done after this filter - groupings , sum etc
```

This gives a resultset of
item_levels prod_types
1       omega       test
2       omega    example
3       omega       test

I know the equivalent in SQL would be

```
WHERE IF(@selected_item != "all" , item_levels  =  @selected_item , 1 = 1  ) AND 
IF(@selected_type != "all" , prod_types =  @selected_item , 1 = 1  )
```

Is there something obvious i am missing here ? I know I could apply several filters and pipe them together , but when theres multiple filters this adds up and I would like to avoid if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to use a helper function that does the `all` comparison for you:

```r
compare_all = function(selected, to_compare) {
  if(selected != "all") {
    to_compare == selected
  } else {
    # Get a vector of only `TRUE` with the same length as `to_compare`
    rep_along(to_compare, TRUE)
  }
}

sample %>% filter(compare_all(selected_item, item_levels) & compare_all(selected_type, prod_types))
```

Not only does this solve your problem, but it's also much cleaner to extend to even more filters, as you only have to add more calls to `compare_all`.